# _xlfn.IFERROR Excel2013 deletion

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub DeleteNames() 
 Dim nName As Name 
  For Each nName In ThisWorkbook.Names 
   If nName.Name Like "_xlfn.*" Then nName.Delete 
  Next nName 
End Sub
```

Not work with error 1004

```
Sub ShowNames() 
 Dim nName As Name 
  For Each nName In ThisWorkbook.Names 
   nName.Visible = True 
  Next nName 
End Sub
```

Not work with error runtime error 438 "object does not support this property or method

How to delete _xlfn.IFERROR named range?

Comment: `_xlfn.IFERROR` is not a named range but a hint that `IFERROR` is not supported by the Excel you are running. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Issue-An-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882f1ef7-68fb-4fcd-8d54-9fbb77fd5025.

Comment: @AxelRichter Actually, yes it is a name - it's created whenever you use a function that was added in 2007, for backward compatibility. There is no point trying to delete it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran in that problem today when I copied a worksheet that contained a named range, which I later deleted from the original worksheet. However the name could not be used because it was still indexed by excel with the .RefersTo value "=#NAME?" and name "_xlfn.IFERROR".
Sadly the faulty named range was not visible in the Name Manager and it also could not be deleted using VBA subroutine, which gave error 1004.

The way I tackled this:
1. Define a subroutine in VBA in a Module of your choice, which will make the faulty named range visible in the Name Manager:

```
Public Sub makeNameJunkVisible()
Dim n As Name
  For Each n In ThisWorkbook.names
    If n.RefersTo = "=#NAME?" Then
      n.visible = True
    End If
  Next n
end sub
```

2. Open Name Manager, which is found in the Formula Tab on the Ribbon Menu
   The faulty named range should now be visible on the Name Manager and you should be able to delete it.

Comment: A small note and an addition to the solution:
You will need to delete all references to the named range or table in any formula before you delete it, otherwise the index would still be there.